Why does Python prepend the name of a class created with `type` with "abc." when the subclass of the class subclasses `ABC`?
In the following snippet the class returned by the type call is named "abc.Y", why? It's defined in the "main" (in this case) module, after all (certainly not in any "abc" module) so I would expect it to be called "__main__.Y".
from abc import ABC

class X(ABC):
    pass

type('Y', (X,), {}) # Creates and returns a type named "abc.Y", why?

Replacing the type call with a more traditional class definition class Y(X): pass, results in the name being "__main__.Y", as one would expect. Interestingly, the name of X is "__main__.X" which is also what you'd expect.
I don't see how dynamically creating the subclass of X, in this case, should somehow make the name to be prefixed with "abc.", even as X itself derives from ABC?
This also happens if ABC is replaced with metaclass=ABCMeta in definition of X. Removing ABC as subclass of X rectifies the issue where Y is then named "__main__.Y".
I can't find anything in the documentation that should hint at the reason behind this naming behaviour. I've read up on abc.ABC and type. Maybe I am missing something very obvious?
(This happens in both Python 3.11 and 3.12)
